# Understanding Task behavior in Swift

Tags: swift, concurrency, task, wwdc

I'm confused by these two seemingly contradictory statements about Swift's concurrency model:

At minute 58 of the WWDC session [Swift Concurrency Code Along](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10194/), the speaker says:

> Remember this handler is running on the main thread, so when we create a Task that task will also be running **on the main thread**

At minute 23 of the WWDC session [Meet Async/Await](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10132/), the speaker says:

> An async Task packages up the work in the closure and sends it to the system for immediate execution on the **next available thread**, like the async function on a global dispatch queue

I am having a hard time squaring these two statements. Is a `Task` similar to `DispatchQueue.global().async` or does it depend on the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked:

> Is a `Task` similar to `DispatchQueue.global().async` or does it depend on the context?

In short, `Task {…}` is not the same as `DispatchQueue.global().async`. That [second quote](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10132/?time=1385) is imprecise.

A `DispatchQueue.global().async` dispatches to the next available worker thread from the thread pool. A `Task {…}`, however, is isolated to the current actor, if any. `Task.detached {…}` is more akin to a dispatch to a GCD global queue than `Task {…}` is. (Note, with the explosion of `async` API, explicitly moving something off the current actor is not nearly as common as it was back in the day. Likewise, if you *really* need to get something off the actor because it is slow and synchronous, there are a ton of [subtle concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74580345/1271826) with Swift concurrency.)

But, as you suggested, context matters. `Task {…}` behaves much like `Task.detached {…}` if invoked from a nonisolated context. I would suggest, though, that if you must get it off the current actor, then it would be best to avoid `Task {…}` and instead use `Task.detached {…}`. The resulting behavior is not context-dependent and the developer’s intent is more obvious.

FWIW, while the compiler is excellent at verifying a type’s actor-isolation, there are edge cases where it is not remotely obvious to the casual reader. (E.g., add a `@StateObject` property to a nonisolated type and it [becomes isolated](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0316-global-actors.md#global-actor-inference)!) It is best not to write code reliant upon assumptions about a type’s lack of actor-isolation. One can make an argument that if you must get it off the current actor, if any, it might be best to do so explicitly. Likewise, if you do not explicitly need it off the current actor, then do not do so unnecessarily.

As an aside, if one really need to get something off the current actor, one might reach for a task group, `async let`, a `nonisolated` `async` function (per [SE-0338](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0338-clarify-execution-non-actor-async.md)), or isolate it to a different actor. It is hard to generalize this. We should avoid unnecessary [unstructured concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency#Unstructured-Concurrency).

---

Let us look at the code referenced in that [second quote](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10132/?time=1385). They `await` a call to the view model’s `fetchImage`:

```swift
struct ThumbnailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    var post: Post

    @State private var image: UIImage?

    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: image ?? placeholder)
            .onAppear {
                Task {
                    image = try? await viewModel.fetchThumbnail(for: post.id)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Given the `await`, we are not too worried about blocking a thread in this case. The whole idea of a *concurrency* system is that the current thread is not blocked while it awaits `fetchImage`.

In fact, if you change that example to use `Task.detached {…}`, you will get an appropriate compile-time error (if you have “Strict concurrency checking” build setting of “Complete”).

---

FWIW, WWDC 2021 video [Swift concurrency: Behind the scenes](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10254) is a great introduction to the threading model underpinning Swift concurrency.

---

While I included the code snippet from the video, above, for the sake of completeness, I will take it to the next step and note that we would probably use a [`.task`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/task(priority:_:)) view modifier:

```swift
struct ThumbnailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    var post: Post

    @State private var image: UIImage?

    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: image ?? placeholder)
            .task {
                image = try? await viewModel.fetchThumbnail(for: post.id)
            }
    }
}
```

In that video, they were walking us through the transition from GCD to Swift concurrency, and that `onAppear` with a `Task` was just one step in the transition. But the `.task` view modifier takes it a step further, not only dropping us in an asynchronous context, but automatically canceling the task if the user leaves the view before the asynchronous work is done.

Comment: BTW, this does not take away from Matt’s answer (+1). Just adding more background info…

Comment: Thanks Rob! I haven't watched that wwdc yet and will remedy that in the morning, along with your other references. Dream team of SO support here. Your added context is much appreciated!

Comment: Here is my attempt at squaring the two speaker's statements in my original post: in the first quote, the isolation context determined that the Task's closure should execute in the same isolation context, which happened to be Main. I've tried to verify what the code looked like (e.g. if the surrounding class was marked MainActor), but the Coffee Tracker sample code has since been updated. In the second quote, the speaker is trying to give us a shortcut for how Task works without all the intricacies of the concurrency model, and reaches for an imperfect analogy.

Comment: I've read this answer a few times and learned something new each time. And the behind-the-scenes WWDC was crucial, there are so many concepts in there to consider. It was particularly interesting to me that we still have to consider actor hopping as costly when dealing with the main actor. In my career, we were told not to think of threads with GCD (think queue!). Now we are told not to think in threads again (actors!). But then you watch a wwdc vid to help us form a mental model, and it's all about threads! It makes sense to me that we need this concept. It's hardware at the bottom w cores.

Comment: “In the second quote, the speaker is trying to give us a shortcut for how Task works without all the intricacies of the concurrency model, and reaches for an imperfect analogy.” … Yeah, that’s my interpretation, too. Spot on.

Answer (score 3):

You're sort of comparing apples with oranges.

The **first quote** is about how the context may determine whether or not a task runs on the main thread. That has nothing to do with the second quote! Obviously `DispatchQueue.global().async` is not going run on the main thread; that's the whole point of specifying the global queue. So no one is saying that Task is like `DispatchQueue.global().async` in *that* sense!

The **second quote**, the one mentioning `DispatchQueue.global().async`, is about what a task *is*. The problem you're having here is that you're misunderstanding what "like the async function on a global dispatch queue" means and what a queue is:

- A queue is not a thread. A queue is a way of mustering threads.
- When you say `DispatchQueue.global().async`, you are not dictating what thread the queue will actually use; you are saying "If you find a (non-main) thread available, do the work on that."

And that is what a Task does as well. So they are certainly similar in that sense. The big difference (or one big difference anyway) is that if a Task waits in the middle, it might resume on a different thread — whereas a dispatch queue, having picked a thread, must stick to it until the code ends.

Comment: Thanks matt! I actually understand your two bullets well. And I agree that the last paragraph is an important distinction between GCD APIs and the Task (in my experiments I have seen a Task resume on a different thread after being suspended at an await). My question at the bottom of the post was meant to highlight the differences in description used by the two speakers. My confusion, then, is what set of rules should I keep in my head to know that a Task's closure will be executed on the main thread versus an arbitrary global thread. In some cases I really don't want to be on main

Comment: Researching this, I found what I think is an answer in the apple docs: "... the task created by `Task.init(priority:operation:)` inherits the priority and actor context of the caller, so the operation is treated more like an asynchronous extension to the synchronous operation." That doesn't make total sense to me at the moment, but it's a start. If a function body is executing in the context of a @MainActor, a Task within that body will also be on the main thread

Comment: In practical terms I find it very difficult to know whether a Task will run on the main thread or not. For the most part, you shouldn't care. Learning to stop thinking about threads is probably the hardest part of using Swift concurrency.

Comment: You can see me puzzling about the matter here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67954414/what-determines-whether-a-swift-5-5-task-initializer-runs-on-the-main-thread

Answer (score 0):

The second phrase was said without a context of the solved task:

> An async Task packages up the work in the closure and sends it to the system for immediate execution on the next available thread, like the async function on a global dispatch queue

It was about **any** `Task {` in general.

In the context of that task (`onAppear { Task {…} }`) the only available thread is `main` because all `Tasks` launched from the main thread will be executed on the main thread (formally it's more complicated, but shortly it's so). So,

> Is a Task similar to DispatchQueue.global().async or does it depend on the context?

Second - Task depends on the context.